# word wrap in a div?

Tags: html, text, word-wrap

I am trying to wrap text in a div.  Any way to do that?

Here's the code in question:

```
<div width="700"><pre><p> " . $texts . "</p></pre></div>
```

Any clue?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said it's not wrapping after 700 px.  Rather, it's just making scrollbars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.longren.org/2006/09/27/wrapping-text-inside-pre-tags/

"The long lines are caused by use of the pre html tag. The pre tag preserves spaces and line breaks in a chunk of text. Perfect for displaying snippets of code. However, some lines of code are quite long and will run off the page. This is exactly why my sidebar was getting pushed to the bottom of the page in IE."

To fix:

```
pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: Where do i put this?  it's a very simple site with no CSS.

Comment: Either put it in a CSS file (and include the file), inline in a `style` tag or on the `div` element using the `style` attribute.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out:<style type="text/css">
</style>  Thanks!

Comment: Btw you could remove the "pre" tags if the contents are not meant to be "preformatted text".  This would fix the issue, but if the content is really meant to be preformatted then you should leave the pre tag.

Comment: it needs to be there.  Thanks!